# Silverlight 4 Screen Capture

Tags: silverlight-4.0, screenshot

I'm writing a timesheet helper utility in Silverlight 4. This will be a trusted out of browser application that will periodically ask the user (with a SL4 Notification Window) what they have been working on. What I'd like to do is have it capture images of their desktop (or better yet, active window) from time to time in order to remind them of what they have been working on since they last submitted their status report. Is this idea even possible? Do I need to use COM? If so, what COM component would I use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any installed COM object you could use -- you'd have to create one and install it.