# Silverlight: converting WriteableBitmap to stream

Tags: silverlight, image-processing, writeablebitmap

Given a WriteableBitmap, how can I save the bitmap back into an image stream (JPG or BMP)?

My scenario is:

1. Show OpenFileDialog, let user select image
2. Load image into WriteableBitmap
3. Resize image
4. Send image stream to web service

Step #4 is what I'm having trouble with. How can I go from WriteableBitmap -> Stream?

Comment: Check this link, it takes help of third party:
http://blog.blueboxes.co.uk/2009/07/21/rendering-xaml-to-a-jpeg-using-silverlight-3/

Comment: That link uses the FJCore library, which only supports JPG encoding.

Comment: Similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841534/silverlight-4-screen-capture/8560271#8560271

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so Silverlight doesn't have anything built-in to turn a WriteableBitmap into an image stream.

After much wailing and gnashing of teeth, I found the excellent open source [ImageTools library for Silverlight](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/), which provides encoders and decoders for JPG, BMP, GIF, and PNG.